# ZF2 2.2.4 issue with translator

Tags: php, zend-framework2, po-file

I have an issue since i passed from ZF 2.2.0 to ZF 2.2.4 on my website, change language doesn't work.

This is my autoload/translator.global.php

Without change the source code, just switch to 2.2.0 it works, 2.2.4 is not.

```
<?php
return array(
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem, since 2.2.1, you must use an alias

```
<?php
return array(
'service_manager' => array(
    'allow_override' => 'true',
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'mvcTranslator',
    ),

),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I have to wait for tomorrow ^^